# Google maps not smooth on S4

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i've searched everywhere for any answer with no luck. I've been developing an app for android that uses google maps android api v2 and my main testings device is Samsung s4. Through the development i found the map not smooth for a phone that fast, but i thought that this was a universal thing when i had the same problem with the nexus7. A few days back i tested it on an Sony Xperia Z and it was very smooth, so does anyone have any idea why is this happening or how to solve it.

Event the simple map fragment is not smooth here is the code:

```
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

It is stutters and lagyys when you zoom and move the map, this is not only in my app its also present in the google maps app, but when i used the Xperia Z it didn't have that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the screen display is laggy ? Please show your Map codes.

Comment: Does it lag when running samples? Without the code we can't tell what bad things you did.

Comment: Well the thing is that it also lags when i use the normal google maps app, I edited the question and included a sample

Comment: Well if the normal maps lags, then the one you are doing would be the same... Is it the i9500 or i9505? I'm using the i9505 and I have no maps issues. Are you on latest firmware, or on a ROM?

Comment: Its a I9505 with the latest firmware(XXUBMGC) 4.2.2 jellybean and i have the latest updates. Maybe it Samsung's bloatware that was my first guess, but that's not a satisfactory answer for me. Its not a major issue lie 4sec lagg, it is just not that smooth and thats bad for me because the map is the main component of the app.